# expressjs - unable to process request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am learning nodejs / expressjs and shoehorning it into the Spring MVC pattern because I figure I can keep my file's cohesive.  But it's not quite working out as I would expect...

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser= require('body-parser');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const app = express();

var PeopleController = require('./controller/PeopleController.js')
var db;

app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  var path = req.url;
  var controller;

  switch (true) {
    case /\/people.*/g.test(path):
      controller = new PeopleController();
      console.log("people");
      controller.process(req, res, next);
      break;
    case /\/foo.*/g.test(path):
      console.log("foo");
      break
    default:
      console.log("nada");
      break;
  }
});
```

PeopleController.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser= require('body-parser');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const app = express();

var PeopleController = function PeopleController() {}

PeopleController.prototype.process = function (req, res, next) {
  var baseURL = '/people';

  console.log('path is ' + req.path);

  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

  app.get(baseURL, (req, res) => {
    console.log('people get');
  });

  app.post(baseURL, (req, res) => {
    console.log('people post');
  });
};

module.exports = PeopleController;
```

Then when I do a GET on /people/ I get the following console out...

```
people
path is /people/
```

I expect the app.get to run and to get the following output:

```
people
path is /people/
people get
```

Comment: From what I can see you create a new instance of `app` but it's not listening on any ports. `app.get` will match the request to the port that it's listening to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lurk I'd highly recommend using `express.router` like so:

```
PeopleController.js

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// then apply middleware
router.use(...);

// then define your endpoints
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log('get PeopleController.js root');
}

module.exports = router;
```

In server.js

```
...
const PeopleController = require('./controller/PeopleController.js');

// apply PeopleController to '/people' route
app.use('/people', PeopleController);
```

So now when you request GET /people you should see the console.log on node. The big benefit of this approach is it keeps your code clean (no switching based on route, you let express handle restful actions)

Comment: I think I like this approach better than the other approach. Can you apply this router/controller concept for `app.method` and not only just for middleware?

Comment: Hi char, not sure I'm understanding your question. The pattern here is to group endpoints e.g. suppose PeopleController has GET /sayHello and POST /reproduce and AnimalController has GET /makeNoise and POST /offspring endpoints. You'd 'attach' them with app.use('/people', PeopleController) and app.use('/animal', AnimalController). Finally consume them with POST /animal/offspring. If you're asking about grouping endpoints by method (e.g. all GET calls in one file) then that's a different pattern I'm not familiar with.

Comment: This was a clean solution.  Thank you.

Comment: Good work. I was actually structuring my api in a similar way to you initially until a good fellow on github told me better!

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you have only one instance of Express listening on port.

In server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser= require('body-parser');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const app = express(); // we create an instance of Express
...
app.listen(process.ENV.PORT); //this specific instance listening on port
```

When you creating new instance of PeopleController you must past an `app` in server.js

```
const app = express();
...
controller = new PeopleController(app);
```

And import in PeopleController.js

```
const express = require('express'); // delete this
const app = express(); // delete this

//add this:
var PeopleController = function PeopleController(appInstance) {
  this.app = appInstance;
}

PeopleController.prototype.process = function (req, res, next) {
  var baseURL = '/people';
  var app = this.app;

  console.log('path is ' + req.path);

  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

  app.get(baseURL, (req, res) => {
    console.log('people get');
  });

  app.post(baseURL, (req, res) => {
    console.log('people post');
  });
};
```